# What is the best header structure to use in a library?

Tags: c++, header

Concerning headers in a library, I see two options, and I'm not sure if the choice really matters. Say I created a library, lets call it `foobar`. Please help me choose the most appropriate option:

1. Have one include in the very root of the library project, lets call it `foobar.h`, which includes all of the headers in the library, such as "src/some_namespace/SomeClass.h" and so on. Then from outside the library, in the file that I want to use anything to do with the `foobar` library, just `#include <foobar.h>`.
2. Don't have a main include, and instead include only the headers we need in the places that I am to use them, so I may have a whole bunch of includes in a source file. Since I'm using namespaces sometimes as deep as 3, including the headers seems like a bit of a chore.

I've opted for option 1 because of how easy it is to implement. OpenGL and many other libraries seem to do this, so it seemed sensible. However, the standard C++ library can  require me to include several headers in any given file, why didn't they just have one header file? Unless it's me being and idiot, and they're separate libraries...

#### Update:

Further to answers, I think it makes sense to provide both options, correct? I'd be pretty annoyed if I wanted to use a std::string but had to include a mass of header files; that would be silly. On the other hand, I'd be irritated if I had to type a mass of `#include` lines when I wanted to use most of a library anyway.

#### Forward headers:

Thanks to all that advised me of forward headers, this has helped me make the header jungle less complicated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

stl, boost and others who have a lot of header files to include they provide you with independent tools and you can use them independently.

So if you library is a set of uncoupling tools you have to give a choice to include them as separate parts as well as to include the whole library as the one file.

Answer (score 5):

Think a bit about how your libary will be used, and organize it that way. If someone is unlikely to use one small part without using the whole thing, structure it as one big include. If a small part is independent and useful on its own, make sure you can include just enough for that part. If there's some logical grouping that makes sense, create include files for each group.

As with most programming questions, there's no one-size-fits-all answer.

Answer (score 2):

All #included headers have to be processed.  This isn't as bad as it could be, since modern compilers provide some sort of option for not processing them repeatedly (perhaps with something like `#pragma once`, or an `ifndef` guard).  Still, every #included header has to be processed once for each translation unit, and that can add up fast.

The usual practice is for header files to #include only those header files they need, and to use forward declarations (`class foo;`) as much as possible.  That way, you don't get the overhead.

If you want to #include everything and its brother, you can provide your own header file that #includes everything.  You don't have to explicitly write everything out in every header and source file.  That option is something you can provide, but if everything in std came as one monolithic header, you wouldn't have an option.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you #include a header file you make the compiler do some pretty hard work. The fewer headers you #include, the less work it has to do and the faster your compilations will be.

Answer (score 1):

All include files should have own sense. And you should choose header structure from lib-users positions: how users should use my library? what structure will best for users?

**examples:**
if you library provide string algorithms - it will be better make one header with all - string_algorithms.h;
if you library provide some one facade object - it will be better to use one header file ( maybe few other files with extensions or helpers );
if you provide complex of objects which will be used independently make different header files (containers lib provide different containers);

Answer (score 1):

[Forward declare](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml) instead of including all those header files at once, then include as and when you need.

Answer (score 1):

However you decide on the header file(s) that you make available (one, several or some combination thereof) for the library's public API, it's always a good idea to have at least one separate header for the private API. (No need to expose the prototypes of the non-exported functions and classes or the definitions that are only intended to be used internally.)